# useRef not tracking selected items in dropdown

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have dynamic dropdowns and im using useRef to keep track of what's been selected so that the next dropdown does not show items already selected. However, when I delete an item, previous dropdowns show all options again.

However when I remove an item, the other dropdowns don't track everything that's still selected.

For example here, if you creat 3 items, select 1 through 3, then delete the last one. If you go back to the first dropdown you'll see option 2 is in the left even those it's already selected. 
https://codesandbox.io/s/actions-selector-t7nbk?file=/ObjectList.jsx

```
  const gSettings = useRef(globalSettings);
  const [object, setObject] = useState('user');
  const objectOptions = (
    objects.filter(i => !gSettings.current.map(i => i.object).includes(i)) || []
  ).map(i => ({ value: i, label: i }));
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are [shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) your `i` variable in this statement:

```
objects.filter(i => !gSettings.current.map(i => i.object).includes(i))
               ^                           ^
```

Use a different variable name in the `map` callback, `k` for example:

```
objects.filter(i => !gSettings.current.map(k => k.object).includes(i))
```

Or you can move the inner `map` above:

```
const selectedOptions = gSettings.current.map(i=> i.object)
objects.filter(i => !selectedOptions.includes(i))
```

---

As a side note, it would help to make the variable names more explicit.

Comment: Ah, fixed that but that doesn't address the issue unfortunately.